# Toshiba Laptop Ventilator (almost) turns off after boot

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, cooling, toshiba-laptop

So my Laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L550.

The problem I have is that it overheats quite often. I know that the ventilator is rarely turned on, despite `sensors` returns a high temperature of about 70 Degree Celsius.

I have searched online, but have not found anything specific.

Here are the things I tried:

Checked if the toshiba_acpi kernel module is loaded.

`dmesg | grep -i Toshiba` returns

```
[    0.000000] DMI: TOSHIBA Satellite L550/KTWAA, BIOS V1.90 12/18/2009
[    0.010022] TOSHIBA Satellite detected - force copy of DSDT to local memory
[    1.174126] ata2.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MK4055GSX, FG011M, max UDMA/100
[    1.175004] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MK4055GS FG01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   13.105390] toshiba_acpi: Toshiba Laptop ACPI Extras version 0.19
[   13.105466] input: Toshiba input device as /devices/virtual/input/input6
```

From what I understood this means that it has been loaded.

Then I checked what ls `/proc/acpi/toshiba/` returns

```
keys
version
```

`cat keys` gives me a not very descriptive filecontent of:

```
hotkey_ready:            0
hotkey:                  0x0000
```

`cat version` gives:

```
driver:                  0.19
proc_interface:          1
```

I then found out about acpitool. Running acpitool -T complains that it thinks that I have not enabled the toshiba_acpi module. From what I have gathered 'enabling' in this context means that you simply have to load it. (which it is)

I then also tried setting setting my boot option to acpi_osi="Windows" and "Linux". Both  have changed nothing, despite knowing that when running under Windows 7 the Ventilator was happily running. (Even if loud, but that's better than simply turning off.)

In relation to the title, the Ventilator blows on what I believe is full speed before booting. While in the boot menu (syslinux if that makes a difference). Once the booting starts it drops dramatically before turning on very slightly. But that also slowly fades into nothing.

If there is any more info you need I will happily give that as well.

I am running on Arch Linux.

`uname -a` gives me:

```
Linux ponyville 3.12.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 12 12:57:31 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you find out what kernel messages come before and after `[   13.105390] toshiba_acpi: Toshiba Laptop ACPI Extras version 0.19`? It's possible that it's starting to load and then failing and being unloaded for some reason.

Comment: Here is the full output: http://pastebin.com/NjtDaR1v

I saw some perhaps interesting things now that might be coupled to my issue at around `[0.114805]`

Comment: Look at lines 816 and 817 on that pastbin output. The default ACPI driver appears to fail with a conflict, so it probably isn't running at all when the system is on.

Comment: Can you try and load either ACPI program from the command prompt and see if that works, or does it have to load at boot time?

Comment: @K.A, well I did a `# modprobe toshiba_acpi` and nothing happened. `lsmod` tells me that it is already loaded.